# How can you view the code for the example Community Visualizations in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, visualization, looker-studio

I am trying to make a Sankey chart (alluvial diagram) in Data Studio. I have found the "Community Visualizations" page and I can see the sankey diagram is one of the examples (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/). However, when I try to look in the bucket public-community-viz-showcase-reports, despite these supposedly being public it says I don't have the appropriate permissions to view them. I want to view the code used to generate the showcase report so I can modify it for my own purposes (I need to add color coding of the flows and multiple columns). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the files were uploaded to the [Community Visualizations repository](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/tree/master). The Sankey one was marked as experimental and deleted in this [commit](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/commit/e93855493b332955b11f1e40ab644ab5a4a51151). The reason can be due to updating it to the [new version](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/issues/15) but we aware of that if using it in production. Anyway, you can still browse through the repository history to find older files containing the original code. For example:

- Sankey [folder](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/tree/4cfd48a532f94fc8b2a1a1cb245de8f561cbd921/viz/sankey)
- [index.js](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-visualizations/blob/4cfd48a532f94fc8b2a1a1cb245de8f561cbd921/viz/sankey/src/index.js)

Note that it also contains instructions on how to build the visualizations with the new changes you apply to the code.

By the way, even if you don't have `storage.objects.list` to run `$ gsutil ls gs://public-community-viz-showcase-reports/sankey` you do have `storage.objects.get` and can retrieve individual files of course. The problem in doing it that way is that files are minified to improve performance and not really readable.

As an example, an excerpt of `index.js`:

```sh
$ gsutil cat gs://public-community-viz-showcase-reports/sankey/index.js | head -c 500
```

is the following:

```js
!function(t){var n={};function e(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var i=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[r].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,e),i.l=!0,i.exports}e.m=t,e.c=n,e.d=function(t,n,r){e.o(t,n)||Object.defineProperty(t,n,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},e.r=function(t){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(t,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})},e.t=function(t,n){if(1&n&&(t=e(t)),8&n)return t;if(4&n&&"object"==typeof t&&t
```

Answer (score 0):

The files for several of the example community visualizations now lives in the [experimental-visualizations](https://github.com/googledatastudio/experimental-visualizations) repository.